# Make Firefox instances open directly on top of each other

Tags: windows-7, firefox, multiple-instances

How can I set Firefox to default to opening directly on top of each other - not 100px to the right or whatever it is?

Comment: It is the window manager that is determining the default location of new windows as they are created, except where the programs themselves explicitly set themselves to "centered" or other such placement (like Maximized).  That doesn't answer your question, but should help shed some light on your subject.

Answer (score 1):

**[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)** will do this for you.

only one of many features:

> Align window at position you specify.
>   It includes top left, top center, top
>   right, middle left, middle center,
>   middle right, bottom left, bottom
>   center, bottom right.

*AWM is freeware.*

Comment: That's a good answer, but since I already use DeskPins happily, and don't need any of the other features - and wouldn't even use this except for Firefox. Not only that but I actually don't see a feature to open window "on top of last program instance", which is very specifically what I'm looking for. The best answer (if possible) would be something like a target flag, similar to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -P "Extension Testing"

Comment: i'm not even 100% sure if Auto Windows Manager offers 'custom alignment', i'm using Actual Windows Manager (which is not free) and this one definitely allows to apply custom alignment rules for any program window.